# Makefile and rsync error: Failed to exec ssh: No such file or directory

Tags: makefile, rsync

I'm trying to publish local files on a mac to my server using rsync and a makefile. 
When running the make command i get the following error:

```
rsync: Failed to exec ssh: No such file or directory (2)  
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/pipe.c(86)   [sender=2.6.9]  
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]  
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [sender=2.6.9]  
make: *** [deploy] Error 14
```

Strange thing is, the rsync command will work if i enter it directly in the shell.

Here's the interesting parts of the makefile:

```
USER = admin  
SERVER = 92.243.xx.xx  
PATH = d_ghost1/www/sub.domain.de/htdocs/  

deploy:  
    /usr/bin/rsync -avz \  
    --exclude '.git*' \  
    --exclude '.DS*' \  
    --exclude '*.log' \  
    --exclude 'config.ini\*' \  
    --exclude 'backend/config.ini\*' \  
    ./{assets,backend,frontend,templates,waffle} $(USER)@$(SERVER):$(PATH)
```

Can anyone make sense of this? 
Thanks, 
Lutz

Comment: I don't know rsynch, but is it possible that it works in some shells and not others? There are several things you can do narrow the problem down-- I'd start with a rule that does `which ssh`.

Comment: I did that and the shell used by make knows ssh at /usr/bin/ssh

Comment: All right, next I'd try simplifying the makefile as much as possible while still reproducing the error. Also, Google says that rsync sometimes has trouble finding ssh, so you might try putting a symlink in rsync/bin/, or using `-e /usr/bin/ssh`.

Comment: Damn it.. that was it! I never bothered setting the -e flag because the path to ssh was known to the shell used by make. Thank for making me try it!

Comment: Still the question remains.. Why do i need it? Is there any place i coud set my path on osx so that they would be available for any shell?

Comment: i had the same problem, i found out that ssh is not installed on my system.after installing the ssh, it worked fine.

Answer (score 11):

I experienced the same error recently on a Ubuntu 18.04 docker image. Installing the openssh-client package, as suggested [here](https://www.techietown.info/2017/06/fix-rsync-failed-exec-ssh-no-file-directory/) solved issue for me.

`sudo apt install -y openssh-clients`

Comment: openssh-clients on centos7 lol note the "s" on the end

Comment: `openssh-server` for 22.04 in my case

Answer (score 0):

If you rename your local variable PATH to something like REMPATH, you will not interfere with the system's PATH variable (indicating where to look for executables) and hopefully all should be as you would expect ...

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the file or dir after the `pem` key file. In my case, the server is RHEL AWS EC2. And I excluded the `nic` directory. It worked 100%.

See the example CMD:

```
rsync -avze "ssh -i /home/ec2-user/MV-UAT-Key.pem" --exclude 'nic' /Sorcepath/home/ec2/synctestEFS/* root@DestinationIPaddress:/home/ec2-user/synctestUAT/
```